# Should I use quote = "all" for readr::write_excel_csv

Tags: excel, export-to-csv, export-to-excel, byte-order-mark, readr

In the documentation* from readr::write_csv I see that quote is set to `quote = c("needed", "all", "none")`

In the documentation* from readr::write_excel_csv I see that quote is set to "all" by `quote = "all"`.

Is there a reason for this difference?

At least it is possible to use readr::write_excel_csv with `quote = "needed"`. And it seems to work fine at first sight: I can open the csv correctly in Excel and if I open the csv file with Notepad there are not quotations around each field as with the use of `quote = "all"` (or is there a reason it could be desirable to have everything quoted?).

*) Please see documentation:

https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/write_delim.html

Thanks a lot!